# Replace N formulas to one (string interpolation)

Tags: c++, string

Is it possible in c++ to do such string conversion as:

Example:

From:

```
F = a && b && c;
H = p ^ 2 + w
K = H > 10 || e < 5;
J = F && !K;
```

To:

```
J = (a && b && c) && !( (p ^ 2 + w) > 10 || e < 5);
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  If in doubt, consult the [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @HenriMenke I mean to convert it from the first form to the other. I guess some kind of recursion is in place, maybe my question is not very clear and people started downvoting for that reason.

Comment: ` a && b && c;` returns bool values

Comment: @Raindrop7 Context is an example.

Comment: @AnnaK. The two code snippets are not equivalent by the way.  https://godbolt.org/g/SrJwv8

Comment: @HenriMenke `p` and `w` are not boolean

Comment: @AnnaK. That's not hard to notice.  In my example `e`, `p`, and `w` are integers.  Also that does not change the statement that the two lines are not equivalent, which is also why the compiler can *never* turn one into the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're asking for [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). In which case sure!
First you'll want to construct a `map<string, string>` of the keys and values, for example:

```
map<string, string> interpolate = { { "F"s, "a && b && c"s }, { "H"s, "p ^ 2 + w"s }, { "K"s, "H > 10 || e < 5"s }, { "J"s, "F && !K"s } };
```

Then just use [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each),
 [`stding::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), and [`string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).

```
for(const auto& i : interpolate) for_each(begin(interpolate), end(interpolate), [&](auto& it){ for(auto pos = it.second.find(i.first); pos != string::npos; pos = it.second.find(i.first, pos)) it.second.replace(pos, i.first.size(), '(' + i.second + ')'); });
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/yBs4PQ)

After running this code, when outputting `interpolate` with `for(const auto& i : interpolate) cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << endl` You'll get:

> F : a && b && c
>   H : p ^ 2 + w
>   J : (a && b && c) && !((p ^ 2 + w) > 10 || e < 5)
>   K : (p ^ 2 + w) > 10 || e < 5

Comment: Not only you understood my question but you covered the theory behind this (and imparted us, those that do not how to name this type of problem, a little more wisdom) *and* you provided an example. People who down-voted this should take example from you Sir: first you read the question to understand what's being asked *then* you judge and possibly give a valid reason why you downvoted . Thank you so much for keeping this site bright like a diamond!

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of `s` after each string?

Comment: @AnnaK. That's the [`""s` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s). `"F"s` is equivalent to `string("F")`.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I think there is a minor flaw with a special case: what happens if we have a circle like: `J = J && F && !K;`? (live compiler seems to abort).

Comment: @AnnaK That would be an infinite loop, no matter how many times you interpolated J there would still be a J that needed to be interpolated. So no, my algorithm cannot output an infinitely repeating sequence, but since neither can anything else... I'm not gonna consider that a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I put it wrong maybe: what if instead of looping through infinite times, the moment it saw a cycle recursion, it stopped (for that particular variable analysis).

Comment: @AnnaK. You can do that with a conditional of course. But if you find you need help writing it, it's outside the scope of your original question, so you'll need to post a new question on that. If you post a link I'll gladly come take a stab at answering.

Comment: I have a problem porting it to c++98: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637892/port-string-interpolation-from-c14-to-c98