# port string interpolation from c++14 to c++98

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm trying to port this answer: [Replace N formulas to one (string interpolation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102989/replace-n-formulas-to-one-string-interpolation) to a standard c++98 implementation.

C++14 version:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, string> interpolate = { { "F"s, "a && b && c"s }, { "H"s, "p ^ 2 + w"s }, { "K"s, "H > 10 || e < 5"s }, { "J"s, "F && !K"s } };

    for(const auto& i : interpolate) for_each(begin(interpolate), end(interpolate), [&](auto& it){ for(auto pos = it.second.find(i.first); pos != string::npos; pos = it.second.find(i.first, pos)) it.second.replace(pos, i.first.size(), '(' + i.second + ')'); });

    for(const auto& i : interpolate) cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << endl;
}
```

C++98: Making the map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> interpolate_map;
interpolate_map.insert(std::make_pair("F", "a && b && c" ));
interpolate_map.insert(std::make_pair("H", "p ^ 2 + w" ));
interpolate_map.insert(std::make_pair("K", "H > 10 || e < 5" ));
interpolate_map.insert(std::make_pair("J", "F && !K" ));

for (const std::pair<const std::string, std::string> & i : interpolate_map)
/* ??? */
```

It's unclear to me how to proceed.

Comment: Convert the lambda to a functor.

Comment: I've posted a [map_init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207976/how-to-easily-map-c-enums-to-strings/208003#208003) helper before. Even C++98 can be made readable by a reasonable dose of helper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of involved [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) in that, whoever wrote it really knows his stuff.

The code that you're looking at uses a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) style `for`-loop, a `for_each`-loop, and a traditional `for`-loop to effectively do three things:

1. Loop through all the keys that could be interpolated
2. Loop through all the value strings to interpolate
3. Loop through the entire string to interpolate all keys

In [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) your best bet is likely just a triple nested `for`-loop:

```
for(map<string, string>::iterator i = interpolate.begin(); i != interpolate.end(); ++i) {
    for(map<string, string>::iterator it = interpolate.begin(); it != interpolate.end(); ++it) {
        for(string::size_type pos = it->second.find(i->first); pos != string::npos; pos = it->second.find(i->first, pos)) {
            it->second.replace(pos, i->first.size(), '(' + i->second + ')');
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/jrNHON)

Comment: It works except from the live demo (in my compiler) because the map can't be initialized like that (I used the initialization like I have it in the question instead). Kudos Mr Mee.

Comment: @AnnaK. You should be allowed to brace initialize a `map` but if your compiler is being ornery the `insert` method works.

Comment: I get this: error: in C++98 ‘interpolate’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’ and warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: @AnnaK. You are correct on the initialization it seems, I thought that gcc6.3 defaulted to C++03 without a flag, turns out it defaults to C++14. Thus I'm really using `map`'s `initializer_list` constructor, which of you correctly surmise is *not* available in C++98: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44654713/2642059